# Create user with only SELECT and INSERT permissions

Tags: permissions, sql-server-2017

I'm working on a project that requires a database user to have only `SELECT` and `INSERT` permissions for all tables in a database.

The following question provides a solution but I'd have to run the script every time I add a new table. Seems like it's specific to SQL Server 2000.

- [How do I create a user in SQL-Server that only has access to one table, and can only insert rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204118/how-do-i-create-a-user-in-sql-server-that-only-has-access-to-one-table-and-can/)

There must be an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have only a single schema `dbo`. So, instead of adding permissions to each table, it's easier to add it to the schema.

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON SCHEMA::dbo to [my_user]
```

This way, each time a table is added to that schema the permissions will be applied automatically. For all my projects the schema rarely change (compared to the number of times a new table is added) so it's acceptable to run this one if a new schema is added.

Maybe other answers would provide a solution where the permissions can be applied at the database level?

Comment: To grant for the whole database just use `GRANT SELECT, INSERT to [my_user]`

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft really? urgh, "couldnt see the forest for the trees" or something!